# 'Problem' with login_redirect filter - why does it lose the redirect_to parameter

Tags: filters, login

This has kept me busy all day and I just want to clarify my understanding as this seems really bizarre behaviour if this is by design.

I am redirecting  the login according to roles by using the filter on the login redirect hook:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'partner_pages_redirect', 10,3 );
```

The simplified function is:

```
function partner_pages_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user  ) {
        
switch($status){
                case "Partner":
                    if(empty($redirect_to)){
                    return site_url();
                    } else {
                        return $redirect_to;
                    }
                case "Lapsed Partner":
                case "Friend":
                    hub_logout_current_user($status);
                    break;
                }
          }
```

However, what I notice is that the $redirect_to arg only has the query string value on the initial load of the login page (this is the vanilla WordPress login page) if the user is not logged in.  As expected, this contains the url of the page they were trying to access but are now being prompted to login. After login, you would expect it to forward onto that page.

However, when you click 'Login' it has already been reset so you cannot redirect to the page the user was trying to access. I worked around it by storing the initial value in a session as all attempts at putting it in a global, in a static var etc. failed.

Am I missing something in using this filter?